# store IP and subnet mask number in a variable and edit on it in Python

Tags: python, ip, subnet

I want to code an application that help me to determine class of IP and edit on it like if I'm using IP class a "10.0.0.0" with subnet mask 255.0.0.0 I want to let user input his IP AND SUBNET MASK as above and I make an equation to inform him how many IPs he can use, during my search I got this code

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write("Enter IP address: ")
sys.stdout.flush()
ip = sys.stdin.readline()
print("you entered: " + ip)
```

but when I use it I couldn't make any edit on the ip by that code

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write("Enter IP address: ")
sys.stdout.flush()
ip = sys.stdin.readline()
a = ip + 1
print("you entered: " + ip + "and your IP will be : " + a)
```

it shows that error : TypeError: must be str, not int

finally I want to make that number is applicable to edit on it, and kindly explain you're code to help me understand it correctly.
thanks in advance

Comment: `sys.stdin.readline()` return string. You can not add an integer (`1`) to string (`ip`). And why don't you use `input()`?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539006/python-increment-ipaddress)

Comment: so what should I use instead sys.stdin.readline() ? 
and If I used input how can I store xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in it ? I know input should retrieve a type of variable like int or string or float ...etc

Comment: You can use regular [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function. You don't have to, it is not an issue, but I don't see why would you use `sys.stdin.readline()` instead of `input()`.

Comment: I used it as I got it, I saw someone use that code to store an IP in a variable there for I used it, can you give me an example about how can I use a regular input() and how can I store an IP in a variable to edit on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Python 3.3 you can make use of the [ipaddress — IPv4/IPv6 manipulation library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)

```
import sys
import ipaddress

sys.stdout.write("Enter IP address: ")
sys.stdout.flush()
ip = sys.stdin.readline().strip()   # remove the trailing '\n'
assigned_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip) + 1
print("You entered: " + ip + " and your IP will be: " + str(assigned_ip))
```

Output:

```
Enter IP address: 192.168.1.0
You entered: 192.168.1.0 and your IP will be: 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: you are such a genius I wanna give you more than million like :) I used your code and It works correctly, thank you so much.