# How to get the next network address given the starting network address in python

Tags: python, networking

Is there a way in python to get the next network address from the given start network address. There are ways go get the next host IP using the `ipaddress` module, but is there a way to get the next network itself?

For example, if my start network address `10.1.0.0/16`, then on each iteration I would like to get the next network address as `10.2.0.0/16`, `10.3.0.0/16` and so on.

So in case of `10.1.0.0/16` the network part is the first two octets(10.1) and remaining are the host part. I want the network part alone to be incremented on each iteration, leaving host part as it is, for eg:

```
start_network = ipaddress.ip_network('10.1.0.0/16')

# Now on each iteration I want the below output

In [37]: next(start_network)
Out[37]: IPv4Network('10.2.0.0/16')
In [38]: next(start_network)
Out[38]: IPv4Network('10.3.0.0/16')
```

Tried using subnets options, but as name suggests it will get you the sub networks within the current network

```
In [34]: network = ipaddress.ip_network('10.1.0.0/16')

In [35]: network.subnets()
```

But our requirement is to get the next network address (preferably without any string manipulations)

Comment: I have posted a solution to your specific question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42451377/7311767

Comment: But your answer was about to get the next host IP , whereas my question is to get the next network adress

Comment: What is a next network address?  If my answer does not suffice, suggest editing your question with examples showing what you are expecting.

Comment: With your suggested code for the first iteration the value i will get is 10.1.0.1 (first host IP) where is i need the network ip i.e 10.2.0.0/16

Comment: OK, then the question was closed improperly.  You have a different question.  Please edit the question and explain what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library [ipcalc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipcalc) has routines to make math on ip addresses fairly easy.  As an example an iterator to get the next network range address can be done like:

**Code:**

```
import ipcalc
import itertools as it

network = ipcalc.Network('10.1.0.0/16')
network_addrs = (network + (i + 1) * network.size() for i in it.count())
```

**Test Code:**

```
print(next(network_addrs))
print(next(network_addrs))
print(next(network_addrs))
```

**Results:**

```
10.2.0.0/16
10.3.0.0/16
10.4.0.0/16
```

**Standard Library Only:**

If it would be preferable to not install `ipcalc`, a class that inherits from `ipaddress.IPv4Network` can be constructed.

```
import ipaddress

class BetterIPv4Network(ipaddress.IPv4Network):

    def __add__(self, offset):
        """Add numeric offset to the IP."""
        new_base_addr = int(self.network_address) + offset
        return self.__class__((new_base_addr, str(self.netmask)))

    def size(self):
        """Return network size."""
        start = int(self.network_address)
        return int(self.broadcast_address) + 1 - start
```

**Usage:**

```
import itertools as it

network = BetterIPv4Network(u'10.1.0.0/16')
network_addrs = (network + (i + 1) * network.size() for i in it.count())
```

**Python 3.4:**

Python 3.4 did not accept tuples to init `ipaddress.IPv4Network`.  This code will work around that.

```
class BetterIPv4Network(ipaddress.IPv4Network):

    def __add__(self, offset):
        """Add numeric offset to the IP."""
        new_base_addr = int(self.network_address) + offset
        new_base_addr_str = str(self.__class__(new_base_addr)).split('/')[0]
        return self.__class__(new_base_addr_str + '/' + str(self.netmask))

    def size(self):
        """Return network size."""
        start = int(self.network_address)
        return int(self.broadcast_address) + 1 - start
```

Comment: Can this also be acheived using standard python3 module(ipaddress) ?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible.

Comment: Does this solution have a dependency on python version?  I see an issue with python 3.4.1.  Is there a work around? Error:   AddressValueError: Only decimal digits permitted in "(167903232, '255" in "(167903232, '255.255.0.0')"

Comment: OK.  Python 3.4 support added.

Comment: Can this logic be applied for IPv6 address also ?

Comment: Here is my new question on incrementing IPv6  networks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363103/how-to-increment-and-get-the-next-ipv6-network-address-from-the-current-network