# How to increment and get the next IPv6 network address from the current network address

Tags: python, networking, ipv6

Using standard python packages, how can I get the next few IPv6 network address if we give any IPv6 network address as input. Basically I want to iterate over the network address which was given and on each iteration it should increment and get the next network

For example, if my start network address 4001:1::/32, then on each iteration I would like to get the next network address as 4001:2::/32, 4001:3::/32, 4001:4::/32  and so on.

```
>>> inet = iterate_on('4001:1::/32')
>>> next(inet)
4001:2::/32
>>> next(inet)
4001:3::/32
```

Note: Here is my previous question for [fetching IPv4 networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451187/how-to-get-the-next-network-address-given-the-starting-network-address-in-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library [ipcalc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipcalc) has routines to make math on ip addresses fairly easy.  But if it would be preferable to not install ipcalc, a class that inherits from ipaddress.IPv6Network can be constructed.

#### Code

```
import ipaddress

class BetterIPv6Network(ipaddress.IPv6Network):

    def __add__(self, offset):
        """Add numeric offset to the IP."""
        new_base_addr = int(self.network_address) + offset
        return self.__class__((new_base_addr, self.prefixlen))

    def size(self):
        """Return network size."""
        return 1 << (self.max_prefixlen - self.prefixlen)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import itertools as it
network = BetterIPv6Network(u'4001:1::/32')
network_addrs = (network + i * network.size() for i in it.count())
print(next(network_addrs))
print(next(network_addrs))
print(next(network_addrs))
```

#### Results:

```
4001:1::/32
4001:2::/32
4001:3::/32
```

#### Python 3.4:

Python 3.4 did not accept tuples to init ipaddress.IPv6Network. This code will work around that.

```
import ipaddress

class BetterIPv6Network(ipaddress.IPv6Network):

    def __add__(self, offset):
        """Add numeric offset to the IP."""
        new_base_addr = int(self.network_address) + offset
        new_base_addr_str = str(self.__class__(new_base_addr)).split('/')[0]
        return self.__class__(
            new_base_addr_str + '/' + str(self).split('/')[1])

    def size(self):
        """Return network size."""
        return 1 << (self.max_prefixlen - self.prefixlen)
```